# my dropdown displays only one first alphabet of the data from the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to code in codeigniter using mysql database and using the html tags...now when i try to retrieve the data of the database to the dropdown it only displays the first alphabet.I am using the following code in 
 **VIEW**

```
<select name="country" style="width: 200px;">
  <?php
    foreach($countries as $country)
    {   
       echo '<option value="'.$country['PKCOUNTRY'].'">'.$country['COUNTRYNAME'].'</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

**MODEL**

```
<?php
```

class Countries_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
    {

```
    parent::__construct();

}
```

public function get_countries()
    {

```
    $query = $this->db->get('ISaathiDev.MCountry');
        if ($query->num_rows >= 0)
        {
            foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                $data[$row['pkCountry']]=$row['CountryName'];
            }
            return $data;
        }
}
```

}
    ?>

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php
```

class countries extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Countries_model');
}

public function hey()
{
}


public function country()
{
    //$this->load->view('u_view');
    //log_message('debug', 'hey :Construct');
    //$this->load->view('u_view');
    $this->load->database();
    $data['countries']=$this->Countries_model->get_countries();
    $this->load->view('countries_view',$data);
}
```

}

?>

[image]

Comment: var_dump($countries); ?

Comment: what is $countries ????? array or object ?

Comment: Your $countries should be 2d array.but i don't think it was

Comment: Yeah, it's a datatype error.  Passing into the foreach() statement.  paste the var_dump()?

Comment: how about formatting your `array` to `$newarray['PKCOUNTRY'] = 'COUNTRYNAME'` then use the `form_dropdown('country',$newarray)` option?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the folloing code:

get_Countries(){
    $this->db->select('pkCountry,CountryName');
    return $this->db->get('ISaathiDev.MCountry')->result_array();
}